# Angular: conditional custom pipe in div ngIf*

Tags: angular, pipe, angular-ng-if, angular2-custom-pipes

Is there a way to conditional process an observable data through a custom pipe in an ngIf

I can do something like

```
<div *ngIf="dataFields$ | async | customPipe as fields ">
```

However, I want to have a condition before using customPipe

```
<div *ngIf="dataFields$ | async | <condition> ? customPipe as fields">
```

I only have `if` condition, no `else` block needed. But, I cant figure out whether this functionality exists or not.

Comment: why not pass parameters into your pipe and do your conditions there?

Comment: Passing the condition to pipe at this point, but want the pipe to be cleaner and have condition outside of pipe